# Setting ID in query as IQueryDescriptions OIDFields throwing error?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, query-layer

I have a layer and the query for layer is a select query consisting of ID field in it. This query is being executed on top of Oracle and its throwing an exception for field "ID" when "ID" field is being set as OIDFields in below code. ID is suppose to be the key field for a layer. I tried using try/catch to see what happens and it turns out that below code is setting all the fields in the layer as key. My issue is how can i set an "ID" returned by a select query of a layer as OIDFields.

```
IQueryDescription qd = sw.GetQueryDescription(layerQuery);
try
{                        
    qd.OIDFields = c.OIDFieldName;                                        
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ 

}
qd.GeometryType = c.ShapeType;
qd.SpatialReference = (mapLayer as IFeatureLayer).AreaOfInterest.SpatialReference;
```

Comment: What is the fieldtype for the ID found in  IQueryDescription.Fields ?  With SQL Server I was puzzled to see that it was esriFieldtypeDouble in some cases when I was expecting it to be integer.

Comment: I am using Oracle and the fieldtype is esriFieldTypeOID.

Comment: What are the other property values of qd (e.g. `IsOIDMappedColumn`)?

Comment: Does OIDFields already have a value before you set it?

Comment: Yes, It's just like I take a layer update it to point to different database server for an example from development database server to test database server and then create new feature class and assign it to current layer feature class. See following code.                     sw.CheckDatasetName(mapLayer.Name, qd, out queryClassName);
                    IFeatureClass newFc = sw.OpenQueryClass(queryClassName, qd) as IFeatureClass;                    
                    (mapLayer as IFeatureLayer).FeatureClass = newFc; "sw" is ISqlWorkspace

Comment: Is `c` a featureclass?  If so does c.OIDFieldName match exactly the `IField.Name` in the `qd.Fields` where `IField.Type == esriFieldTypeOID` ?

Comment: c is a featureclass.  for some reason all the fields in select query are present in qd.Fields and ID field is missing from qd.Fields. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe try aliasing the ID column in your sql select statement to a different column name, perhaps ObjectID. I do that in all the SQL I use for querylayers.

Comment: If i do that than i loose my layer extent information for all layers. Extent information is blank when i check layer properties

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, I am sorry. It must be netowrk issue but still adding alias as "ObjectID" does  not solve the problem.

Comment: hmm, maybe post your SQL code, or a sample of some SQL code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: select ID, STARTDATE, ENDDATE  from VIEW_EXCEPTIONS

Comment: What happens if you open arcmap, choose File>add data> Add Query Layer, then paste this code into the Query section, then Next and see if you can choose ID as objectID field.

Comment: It still selects all fields as OID except ID field